# regEx match url config parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regEx to identify custom parameters.

So if I have the url config path:

```
'/myapp/users/:userId'
```

it would match **[':userId']**

or

```
'/myapp/user/:username/profile/:profileId'
```

I need to return **[':username',':profileId']**

So far I have :(.*)/? but it selects everything after the initial found parameter

http://www.regextester.com/?fam=97974

I'm weak on reg ex, can anyone help please?

Comment: [`:([^\/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/BFeYIt/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:(.*)/?` pattern matches the first `:`, then grabs the whole line *greedily* with `.*` and does not have to do anything else but return the match since `/?` matches an empty string (`/?` matches 1 or 0 `/` symbols).

You may use  a negated character class `[^\/]+`:

```
:([^\/]+)
```

Details:

- `:` - a colon
- `([^\/]+)` - 1+ chars other than `/`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CQg79/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `/:(.*?)($|\/)/g`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sl6IBW/1/)

1. Alternative `$` asserts position at the end of the string
2. Alternative `\/` matches the character
3. `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the great explanation